# How to bound slicer with the only one chart on a dashboad page?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

For example, I have 3 different charts on the same Dashboard page. For each of the charts, I want to have a separate horizontal slicers where each of them only interacts with one chart, independently. How to explicate such a relationship - one chart - one slicer? (While by default each slicer changes all other 3 charts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@XSLT-explorer- you should be able to do this by "Edit Interactions" feature.

When you have the slicer highlighted you will see a "Format" pane in the top many and the first button on this page is the one you want. One you enabled "Edit Interactions" some extra icons will apear on the other objects and all object is by default set to filter.

p.s. If this (or another) answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer that helped by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in".